# Window.print is not working in edge after data load using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing

Window.print() is not opening print preview page in edge after loading the data in grid, but without loading the data, print preview screen is working, we are using Reactjs, please help, Thanks in advancde.

Regards

Comment: You should provide a [reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We just use Window.Print(), it works fine in chrome, but not working in edge. print function works in edge if the grid has no data, if the grid/table has data, its not even showing print as pdf popup.

Comment: window.print() not working after hitting cancel button.